# QAudioRecorder detect user not speaking and stop

Tags: qt, audio, record, qaudiorecorder, qmediarecorder

I want to use `QAudioRecorder` to record audio from the user and then use the audio output file for speech to text. I could successfully run and record audio from this example, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimedia-audiorecorder-example.html.

But my problem is, I need to detect if user has stopped speaking while `QAudioRecorder` is actively recording audio. So `QAudioRecorder` should only stop when user is not speaking.

I could stop `QAudioRecorder` for fixed seconds using `QTimer` as below:

```
void AudioRecorder::toggleRecord()
{
    if (audioRecorder->state() == QMediaRecorder::StoppedState) {
        audioRecorder->setAudioInput(boxValue(ui->audioDeviceBox).toString());

        QAudioEncoderSettings settings;
        settings.setCodec(boxValue(ui->audioCodecBox).toString());
        settings.setSampleRate(boxValue(ui->sampleRateBox).toInt());
        settings.setBitRate(boxValue(ui->bitrateBox).toInt());
        settings.setChannelCount(boxValue(ui->channelsBox).toInt());
        settings.setQuality(QMultimedia::EncodingQuality(ui->qualitySlider->value()));
        settings.setEncodingMode(ui->constantQualityRadioButton->isChecked() ?
                                 QMultimedia::ConstantQualityEncoding :
                                 QMultimedia::ConstantBitRateEncoding);

        QString container = boxValue(ui->containerBox).toString();

        audioRecorder->setEncodingSettings(settings, QVideoEncoderSettings(), container);
        audioRecorder->record();
        this->recordTimeout();
    }
    else {
        this->stopRecording();
    }
}

void AudioRecorder::recordTimeout()
{
    QTimer* mTimer = new QTimer(this);
    mTimer->setSingleShot(true);
    connect(mTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(stopRecording()));
    mTimer->start(6000);
}

void AudioRecorder::stopRecording()
{
    audioRecorder->stop();
}
```

But instead of this it should stop recording when user is not speaking. The `QAudioProbe` class has this signal `audioBufferProbed(QAudioBuffer)` which may be helpful to check level of audio but I don't know how to use it and what level can be used to detect if user is not speaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to do more or less the same thing for a while now. There is an example - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-audiolevels-example.html that shows you how implement an audio level meter which should be helpful. The example uses `QAudioInput`. Specifically, it uses `QAudioInput::start(QIODevice * device)` and passes a custom `QIODevice` to implement the audio level meter. The problem with this approach using `QAudioInput` is once you've got the data, it's not easy to encode it and write it out to file where as with `QAudioRecorder` it's simple.

Anyway ... your right `QAudioProbe` is your best bet if you want to record the easy way with `QAudioRecorder`. I adapted the Qt audio level meter example to work with `QAudioProbe` instead of `QAudioInput`/`QIODevice`. See - https://gist.github.com/sam-at-github/bf66e84105cc3e23e7113cca5e3b1772.

One minor issue the level meter needs `QAudioFormat` but `QAudioRecorder` only provides you with a `QEncoderSettings` (Should probably fix code to use the latter. I don't know why *both* `QEncoderSettings` and `QAudioFormat` need to exist ...). You just gotta get a `QAudioDeviceInfo` for the device your using then use `QAudioDeviceInfo::preferredFormat()`.

---

**Relaed Post:** [Qt: API to write raw QAudioInput data to file just like QAudioRecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348496/qt-api-to-write-raw-qaudioinput-data-to-file-just-like-qaudiorecorder)