# Qt: API to write raw QAudioInput data to file just like QAudioRecorder

Tags: qt

I'm trying to monitor an audio input and record the audio to a file but only when a level threshold is exceeded. There seems to be two main options for recording in Qt; [QAudioRecorder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiorecorder.html) and [QAudioInput](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudioinput.html).

*Long story short:* I'm trying to find the API that can take raw audio sample data read from `QAudioInput` and record it to a file just like `QAudioRecorder` does, but strangely it doesn't seem to exist.  To give an example, the setup of the `QAudioRecorder` would be something like the following (but instead of specifying a input device with `setAudioInput()` you pass it sampled bytes):

```c++
QAudioEncoderSettings audioSettings;
QAudioRecorder recorder = new QAudioRecorder;
audioSettings.setCodec("audio/PCM");
audioSettings.setQuality(QMultimedia::HighQuality);
recorder.setEncodingSettings(audioSettings);
recorder.setContainerFormat("wav");
recorder.setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/tmp/test.wav"));
recorder.setAudioInput("default");
recorder.record();
```

---

I'm using `QAudioInput` because I need access to the raw samples. The problem with `QAudioInput` is, Qt does not seem to provide an easy way to take the raw samples I get out of the `QAudioInput` and pipe them into a file encoding them along the way. `QAudioRecorder` does this nicely, but you can't feed raw samples into `QAudioRecorder`; you just tell it which device to record from and how you want it stored.

Note I tried using `QAudioInput` and `QAudioRecorder` together - `QAudioInput` for the raw access and `QAudioRecorder` whenever I need to record, but there is two main issues with that: A) Only one of these can be reading a given device at a time. B) I want to record the data at and just before the threshold is exceeded and not just after the threshold is exceeded.

Comment: Have you solved it? I'm going to try to make a virtual audio device with `QAudioSystemPlugin`.

Comment: ~Sort of. I found a compromise solution that works for me. I'll post explanation as answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using QAudioRecorder+QAudioProbe. There are a couple of limitations though:

Firstly the attached `QAudioProbe` only works if `QAudioRecorder` is actually recording, so I had to write a wrapper over `QAudioRecorder` to switch on/off recording by switching output device to|from actual_file|/dev/null.

Second, as I stated *"I want to record the data at and just before the threshold is exceeded and not just after the threshold is exceeded"*. Well, I had to compromise on that. The probe is used to detect the recording condition, but there is no way to stuff the data from the probe back into the recorder. I mean, I guess you could record to a buffer file in idle state and somehow prepend part of that data ... but the complexity wasn't worth it for me.

Aside; there was [another issue](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/67577-QAudioRecorder-get-stuck-in-states?p=296640#post296640) with `QAudioRecorder` that motivated me to write a wrapper over it. Basically I found `QAudioRecorder::stop()` sometimes hangs indefinitely. To get around this, I had to heap allocate a recorder and delete it and init a new one with each new recording.

Comment: Well, I don't have an audio device at all... So I'm for a longer ride.